# group by day for the past 5 days

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I am trying to select the sum of an integer field for the past 5 days, and I need to group it for each day.

I'm having a bit of issues figuring out the grouping. Here's my sql query so far:

```
select 
    sum(`amount_sale`) as total 
from `sales` 
where the_date >= unix_timestamp((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY))
```

that works fine for generating the sum for all 5 days together, but I need to break this down so that it shows the sum for each of the past 5 days i.e:

> day 1 - $200
>
> day 2- $500
>
> day 3 - $20

etc.

Comment: don't worry quassnoi, we know you're right.

Comment: @scarhand: someone is **wrong** on the internet!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT  DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(the_date)) AS dt, SUM(amount_sale) AS total
FROM    sales
WHERE   the_date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY))
GROUP BY
        dt
```

To returns `0` for missing dates:

```
SELECT  dt, COALESCE(SUM(amount_sale), 0) AS total
FROM    (
        SELECT  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AS dt
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY AS dt
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY AS dt
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 DAY AS dt
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY AS dt
        ) d
LEFT JOIN
        sales
ON      the_date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt)
        AND the_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY
        dt
```

This is not a very elegant solution, however, `MySQL` lacks a way to generate recordsets from scratch.

Comment: this is perfect. i just have one more question - i want it to return a value of 0 for days that have no sales. so if there were 0 rows for yesterday, i want "total" to come back as 0. can you help?

Answer (score 1):

use the format function to return weekday nr: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(the_date, '%w');

Comment: in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score -2):

use between

like select * from XXX where date between date(...) and date(...) group by date Limit 0,5 
should do it

Comment: im not having a problem with getting the past 5 days, im having a problem with grouping by each day. my code already selects the past 5 days from the current day which is how it should be working. using between will just create unecessary code.

Comment: @scarhand The answer actually includes the `GROUP BY` which is what youre after, the use of `BETWEEN` might be better than your original predicate too, but that depends... @Pierre you don't need the `LIMIT` clause as you already limit the query to 5 records via `BETWEEN`.