# how to use Union all query for fetching the records which is not in table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have a_ad_display table in MYSQL Database with the following format

```
╔═════════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ addisplayId ║ restId  ║ clicked ║     displaytime     ║
╠═════════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╣
║          1  ║  20707  ║      0  ║ 2013-03-07 10:50:55 ║
║          2  ║  20707  ║      1  ║ 2013-03-07 10:55:55 ║
║          3  ║  20711  ║      1  ║ 2013-03-08 12:50:55 ║
║          4  ║  20712  ║      1  ║ 2013-03-08 01:50:55 ║
║          5  ║  20707  ║      1  ║ 2013-03-08 10:50:55 ║
║          6  ║  20708  ║      1  ║ 2013-03-09 12:50:55 ║
║          7  ║  20707  ║      1  ║ 2013-03-09 09:50:55 ║
║          8  ║  20708  ║      0  ║ 2013-03-10 10:50:55 ║
║          9  ║  20708  ║      0  ║ 2013-03-11 11:50:55 ║
║         10  ║  20707  ║      0  ║ 2013-03-11 12:50:55 ║
╚═════════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Now what i want is to fetch records of the restId with the last 7 days data

if current date is 2013-3-12 then i want to show data of  2013-3-5 to 2013-3-11

```
     DISPLAY TIME                   CLICKED     count of row(impression)
March, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000            0       0             
March, 06 2013 00:00:00+0000            0       0
March, 07 2013 00:00:00+0000            1       2
March, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000            1       1
March, 09 2013 00:00:00+0000            1       1
March, 10 2013 00:00:00+0000            1       1
March, 11 2013 00:00:00+0000            0       1
```

i want to ignore timing..just want to focus on date while fetching record date wise
i want to fetch the record with restId=10707 with the total count of row for that date in table and the sum of clicks for that date and if there is no record in the table for any date which coming in in last week's date then it should print that date and print 0 in clicked and also in row count column with 0.

i have made one dummy table in SQL fiddle and also applied this query but its not working..so anyone can please guide me...i know its very complex to understand..but if you have any question about my problem..then will clear u to get a solution from your side..

following is my query which not giving proper data

```
select
  displaytime,
  sum(impression) as clicked,
  (count(impression) -1) as impressions
from (
  select
    displaytime,
    a_ad_display.clicked as impression
  from
    a_ad_display
  where
    a_ad_display.displaytime
  BETWEEN
    date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -6 day)
    AND
    CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00')
    and
    restId=10708
    group by
      a_ad_display.displaytime
    union distinct
    select
      CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), 0
    union distinct
    select
      date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -1 day), 0
    union distinct
    select
      date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -2 day), 0
    union distinct
    select
      date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -3 day), 0
    union distinct
    select
      date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -4 day), 0
    union distinct
    select
      date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -5 day), 0
    union distinct
    select
      date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -6 day), 0
) as x
group by
  date(displaytime)
order by
  displaytime
```

please ignore the code  `CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00')` beacuse its just convert my date to user time zone from utc...

here is my sql fiddle link 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73f07/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should display the correct data. Not a very 'clean' solution. You should replace those unions with a calendar table if you really want to include dates that have no data.

```
SELECT IFNULL(z.displaytime, x.displaytime), IFNULL(z.clicked, 0), IFNULL(z.count, 0)  FROM

  (select
    date(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00')) AS 'displaytime', 0 AS 'Clicked', 0 AS 'count of row(impression)'
  union distinct
  select
    date(date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -1 day)), 0, 0
  union distinct
  select
    date(date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -2 day)), 0, 0
  union distinct
  select
    date(date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -3 day)), 0, 0
  union distinct
  select
    date(date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -4 day)), 0, 0
  union distinct
  select
    date(date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -5 day)), 0, 0
  union distinct
  select
    date(date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -6 day)), 0, 0) AS x

LEFT JOIN

  (SELECT
    DATE(displaytime) AS 'displaytime',
    MAX(clicked) AS 'Clicked',
    COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
  FROM 
    a_ad_display
  WHERE (
    displaytime BETWEEN date_add(CURDATE(), interval -6 day) AND CURDATE()
  ) AND restId = 10707 
  GROUP BY DATE(displaytime)) AS z
ON x.displaytime = z.displaytime
```

Comment: thanx for the answer..its worked.but why this is not a clean solution ?

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a cleaner way, but this should work...

```
select
  displaytime,
  sum(clicked) as clicked,
  sum(impressions) as impressions
from (
select
  displaytime,
  clicked,
  impressions
from (
select
  date(displaytime) as displaytime,
  sum(impression) as clicked,
  sum(legit) as impressions
from (
  select
    displaytime,
    a_ad_display.clicked as impression,
  1 as legit
  from
    a_ad_display
  where
    a_ad_display.displaytime
  BETWEEN
    date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -6 day)
    AND
    CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00')
    and
    restId=10708
) as x
group by
  date(displaytime)
) y
union distinct
    select
      date(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00')), 0, 0
    union distinct
    select
      date(date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -1 day)), 0, 0
    union distinct
    select
      date(date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -2 day)), 0, 0
    union distinct
    select
      date(date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -3 day)), 0, 0
    union distinct
    select
      date(date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -4 day)), 0, 0
    union distinct
    select
      date(date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -5 day)), 0, 0
    union distinct
    select
      date(date_add(CONVERT_TZ(CURDATE( ),'+00:00','-11:00'), interval -6 day)), 0, 0
) z
group by
  displaytime
order by
  displaytime
```

Answer (score 1):

Some other solution for `restID 20707`. For 2013-03-10 there is no record for `restID 20707`.

Query **[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dde57/29)**:

```
SELECT d.Date,
(SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(clicked) >0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM a_ad_display
WHERE DATE(displaytime) = d.Date 
AND clicked = 1
AND restId  = 20707  ) Clicked,
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM a_ad_display
WHERE DATE(displaytime) = d.Date 
AND restId  = 20707  ) 'count of row'
FROM 
(SELECT a.Date
FROM
  (SELECT curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY AS Date
   FROM
     (SELECT 0 AS a
      UNION ALL SELECT 1
      UNION ALL SELECT 2
      UNION ALL SELECT 3
      UNION ALL SELECT 4
      UNION ALL SELECT 5
      UNION ALL SELECT 6
      UNION ALL SELECT 7
      UNION ALL SELECT 8
      UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a CROSS
   JOIN
     (SELECT 0 AS a
      UNION ALL SELECT 1
      UNION ALL SELECT 2
      UNION ALL SELECT 3
      UNION ALL SELECT 4
      UNION ALL SELECT 5
      UNION ALL SELECT 6
      UNION ALL SELECT 7
      UNION ALL SELECT 8
      UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b CROSS
   JOIN
     (SELECT 0 AS a
      UNION ALL SELECT 1
      UNION ALL SELECT 2
      UNION ALL SELECT 3
      UNION ALL SELECT 4
      UNION ALL SELECT 5
      UNION ALL SELECT 6
      UNION ALL SELECT 7
      UNION ALL SELECT 8
      UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c) a
where a.Date >= '2013-01-01' and a.Date < curdate()) d
WHERE d.Date >= date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
ORDER BY d.Date
```

Result:

```
|                         DATE | CLICKED | COUNT OF ROW |
---------------------------------------------------------
| March, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       0 |            0 |
| March, 06 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       0 |            0 |
| March, 07 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       1 |            2 |
| March, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       1 |            1 |
| March, 09 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       1 |            1 |
| March, 10 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       0 |            0 |
| March, 11 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       0 |            1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question:

- [group by day for the past 5 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792686/mysql-group-by-day-for-past-5-days)

It's almost identical to what you're doing